# Highcharts multi series drilldown from a csv

Tags: javascript, json, csv, highcharts, drilldown

I am trying to replicate the highcharts drilldown chart, using multiple series in the data and drilldown data, and external source csv/json data files

1. I can easily recreate the drilldown using the examples from highcharts
2. I can create a column chart using csv as source for data
3. I have been able to create a multiseries to multiseries drilldown using this example ttp://jsfiddle.net/7xEhW/496/

What I am struggling with now is how to load the data from csv in a format that is accepted into the drilldown (multiseries)

This is my code for the parsed

http://jsfiddle.net/9gshkdaj/

I can make it work if I insert static data into the drilldown, but any help on how to load this via a csv would be appreciated (I have control over csv format).
My other idea was to use the data.parsed function to modify the data, but I have no idea where to start (although I know it should be possible, as this example is actually loaded from a tsv) http://www.highcharts.com/news/125-new-features-drilldown-and-no-data

Thank you

```
<pre id="sectorData" style="display:none">
Sector,MTD,drillMTD,YTD,drillYTD
EQ,1,EQ-MTD,2,EQ-YTD
FX,2,F
```

Comment: You should be able to load and preprocess your csv data inside your drilldown event function. Look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/30g6jz2k/4/

Comment: Thank you @GrzegorzBlachliński i see this actually loads csv data in the drill down, which I hadn't been able to do. However it doesn't seem to be structured correctly - is there a way to display 2 series in the a drilldown?

Comment: So this is my latest multi series drilldown to multi series http://jsfiddle.net/7xEhW/496/ but how can I load data from external sources? Happy to do it via csv or json? Basically it seems I have to load data1